# Multiple problems after updating to 7.54

Tags: 7, commerce, ajax

I am working on a D7 site with the latest stable version of Commerce and several Commerce Contrib modules. I recently applied the core 7.54 update from 7.53 and it appears to have caused several problems with my DC set up; specifically 1) the Store Admin UI; 2) Cart Shipping Calculations; 3) the addition of Coupons; 4) the system message list (particularly for cart actions doesn't clear, and builds up).

First, all of these symptoms seem to be related to 7.54 because I have the same code base (same module versions) on a test server without the issues.

**Commerce Admin UI** whatever is happening has broken part of the commerce store ui. I cannot add line items to an order (not coupons, not products, not shipping). When I select one of the line item options and click "add line item" the spinning icon appears but it stops. The same behavior occurs regardless of which line item type I choose. I can confirm that this functionality is preserved with 7.53. This seems to be caused by an ajax error "Invalid Form POST Data".

**Commerce Shipping** I have three commerce shipping services, two flat rate, one based on the Postal Code and Weight Module. When a user proceeds through the cart checkout process, the Shipping calculation is not performed and the user can proceed to payment without shipping charges being applied to the order. I receive the follow watchdog error: "Invalid POST data" from ajax referred  by mysite.com/checkout/294/checkout. If the user were to go back to checkout page, the shipping charge is calculated.

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for addressfield_default_values(), called in /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight.module on line 81 and defined in addressfield_default_values() (line 374 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Warning: Missing argument 2 for addressfield_default_values(), called in /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight.module on line 81 and defined in addressfield_default_values() (line 374 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: field in addressfield_default_values() (line 375 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: instance in addressfield_default_values() (line 375 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: instance in addressfield_default_values() (line 376 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: field in addressfield_default_values() (line 408 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: instance in addressfield_default_values() (line 409 of /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.module).
```

I am led to believe that this is an issue with core version 7.54 because these errors don't occur on the 7.53 codebase.

**Commerce Coupon** Adding percentage based coupons also fails with the "Invalid Post Form Data" notification in watchdog. Coupons can be input but they are not applied when submitted. The form simply clears.

**System Message Box** Unclear if this is related, but the system message box also seems to be affected. The system message box keeps every cart action in the box, leading to a larger and larger box. This clears after flushing the cache as an admin, but users do not have this option and therefore cannot clear the message box. [image]

I'm not sure what else to add here, other than recently the server has been throwing PDO errors and crashing with the mysql server going away. It is a large codebase (over 100 modules).

**UPDATE** the module suggested in the [comments here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1694574#comment-11526105) worked. Truncating the cache tables did not work.

Comment: nizz0k, not sure what the issue is here but can you please try few things for me. Remove drupal default caching and issue a command to repair cache_form table. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Hi Ashish, do you mean the javascript and css caching? and is that command for drush?

Comment: Clear the full drupal cache using drupal admin UI or via drush (drush cc). Once that's done, try repairing cache_form table in database.

Comment: The error normally occurs if the caching is enabled on Drupal site. You will need to disable caching (https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914), followed by clearing cache and repairing cache_form table. Once everything is resolved you can go back and enable caching again.

Comment: Thanks, Ashish, I will have to look at this later this afternoon, but I've read the same thing regarding the problem but haven't found much in the way of a clear path to a solution.

Comment: also, I've looked around a little just down. Can you clarify how to fix the cache_form table?

Comment: You can repair table by issuing a repair command in mysql. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html. If you have phpMyAdmin installed on your server you can login to it, select the tables and issue a command to repair your table. See http://imgur.com/a/sVZwd

Comment: I just looked at your advice on how to disable caching and it's D8 specific, this is D7 site, I went  to the performance page and turned off all the caching options

Comment: So, just ran the repair and it says that the storage engine doesn't support repair.

Comment: Oh ok. Just try truncating cache_ tables from your drupal database. You can also try https://www.drupal.org/node/1694574#comment-11526105. Did you run update.php after the update was performed?

Comment: Yes, I ran the update.php with the update, and re-ran it just recently to be sure. Can you expand on truncating the tables? This custom module looks like it could potentially be a good work around. I will have to experiment this evening.

Comment: You can either ssh into the server, login to mysql and issue a truncate table command See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html. 
If you have phpMyAdmin installed on your computer you can go to phpMyAdmin and select the tables you want to truncate (in your cache anything that starts with cache_) and select empty from the command list. See http://imgur.com/a/rnMCN

Comment: don't see the problem about clearing the caches -- as he did this via admin UI ..

Comment: if you post the module as an answer, I'll accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply the patches that commerce kickstart uses .. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart/releases/7.x-2.45

where

- http://drupal.org/files/drupal-865536-204.patch

is form related

the others may not be needed:

- http://drupal.org/files/1275902-15-entity_uri_callback-D7.patch
- http://drupal.org/files/drupal-1470656-14.patch
- http://drupal.org/files/issues/drupal-7.x-allow_profile_change_sys_req-1772316-28.patch
- http://drupal.org/files/issues/install-redirect-on-empty-database-728702-36.patch